# Unable to find libgazebo_ros_control.so in ROS Indigo with Gazebo 2.2

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm currently working toward integration between ROS I and Gazebo 2.2. When working through the tutorial for spawning a URDF in Gazebo, I've run into a small problem. Every time there is an error message:

```
Error [Plugin.hh:152] Failed to load plugin libgazebo\_ros\_control.so: libgazeo\_ros\_control.so: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The simulation still runs (when my graphics card decides to work) but I think this is affecting the camera output. While in Gazebo I can see the output from the camera, and I can see the rostopic /rrbot/camera1/image_raw. In Rviz i can even choose that particular topic, but it warns me that it's not actually receiving an image and the image remains black.

Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide which will make it easier to diagnose the problem. (Side note: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6608/unable-to-find-libgazebo_ros_control.so-in-ros-indigo-with-gazebo-2.2/) by [ImBunting](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/869/imbunting/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [csherstan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/912/csherstan/) on 2014-07-31**:
Did you happen to get this sorted? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For me the hangup was that I had installed indigo pre-release and had some hacks in place to make it work. I needed to change:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It appears that the binary is now available so finally:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control
```

---

Originally posted by [csherstan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/912/csherstan/) with karma: 26 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ImBunting](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/869/imbunting/) on 2014-08-04**:
This fixes the issue. Thank you!